# how do you get find elements with ajax return on page

Tags: php, ajax

html:

```
 <ul>
 <li>Automobile</li>
 <li>Jet</li>
 <li>Ferry</li>
 <li>Subway</li>
 </ul>
```

heres my function to find li then add the user_input to li

```
    $this->load->library('simple_html_dom');

    $html = file_get_html("http://localhost/marketeer/Exercise/pa/4");

    $oldlist = array();


    foreach($html->find('li') as $list){
        array_push($oldlist ,strip_tags($list));
    }

            $newlist = explode(",",$user_input[0]);
    //merge array in $newlist
    $oldlist = array_merge($oldlist,$newlist);

            foreach($oldlist as $li){
        echo "<li>" . $li . "</li>";
    }
```

at first call it was ok it adds

```
 <ul>
 <li>Automobile</li>
 <li>Jet</li>
 <li>Ferry</li>
 <li>Subway</li>
 <li>new1</li>
 </ul>
```

then when i input another `<li>new2</li>`, it replaced with

```
 <ul>
 <li>Automobile</li>
 <li>Jet</li>
 <li>Ferry</li>
 <li>Subway</li>
 <li>new2</li>
 </ul>
```

it was like im calling a static page without the newly added value.
by the way im using ajax to return the function.

Comment: When you run this `$html = file_get_html("http://localhost/marketeer/Exercise/pa/4");` you are going to always get back the original contents of the page. Javascript updates are all on the client's side.

Comment: @FoolishSeth
what do you suggest sir?
is there any other way to pull li including newly added?